# Build output of MVC6 app. How does it works now?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am checking out the default MVC 6 application and published the build on local file system. This how it looks like when i check *Compile source files to nuget pacakges*

I can see 3 main folders: *approot*, *logs* & *wwwroot*

**Inside approot:**

[image]

I can see that my WebApplication1 is now as a nuget package.

1. What is ef file in approot>Packages>WebApplicaton1>1.0.0>app ?
2. ef files are in approot too along with 2 web files. What are they ?

**Inside wwwroot:** It has all my static resources like css and js.

How does all this fall in place when we deploy the application in IIS or azure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ef` and `web` files in the published output correspond to the `ef` and `web` `commands` that you have defined in your `project.json` file. You could define more commands in your project.json file and all of them would show up here.

Starting with `beta-8` version, ASP.NET 5 uses a module in IIS called `HttpPlatformHandler` which forwards http requests to a external process...in our case it would be the `dnx.exe` process. For example, you can take a look at the following `web.config` file under `wwwroot` which shows the module registration and also the path to execute the external process...as you can see here `web.cmd` is being used.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%home%\site\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout.log"></httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This kind of design is suitable for non-Windows scenarios too...for example, you could use your app with the `nginx` reverse proxy too

More deeper details can be found in the following link:

[Change to IIS hosting model](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69)